# Can't run apt install due to unmet dependencies or exists

Tags: apt, kernel, dpkg

I'm trying to update some packages but I keep getting the message "unmet dependencies".

What I do

```
sudo apt update // All good here
sudo apt install --only-upgrade certbot
```

With the apt install I get the following messages (I translated the messages so they will not be correct word by word):

```
It's useful to run "apt-get -f install" to fix the following issues:
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
     certbot : Depends: python3-certbot (= 0.31.0-2~deb10u1+ubuntu16.04.1+certbot+3) but it's not going to be installed
     linux-headers-4.4.0-179-generic : Depends: linux-headers-4.4.0-179 but it's not going to be installed
     linux-image-4.4.0-179-generic : Depends: linux-modules-4.4.0-179-generic but it's not going to be installed
```

The kernel right now is:

```
uname -a
Linux 4.4.0-178-generic #208-Ubuntu SMP Sun Apr 5 23:45:10 UTC 2020 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

So I try to run `apt-get -f install`

```
After this operation, 131MB will be occupiede on disk
Continue? Y/n
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg exited unexpectedly
```

So I read it might have to do with free space in `/boot`, which indeed has A LOT of old kernels, but following all the guides I can't remove.

With `sudo apt-get autoremove --purge` I get again the unmet dependencies warning as before and suggest to run `apt-get -f install`.

If I try to remove a old kernel with `dpkg` the process get killed almost immediately:

```
sudo dpkg --force-all -P linux-image-4.4.0-71-generic
Reading database 95%
Killed
```

With `sudo dpkg --configure -a` I get

So I'm quite stuck and tried almost everything out there

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem wasn't disk space, even if it's a good idea to clean the order kernels since they were occupying 8GB.

The problem was not having enough RAM. The server has only 512MB and the process was getting killed because of that.

I solved it by making a swap file by following this guide: https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-16-04

After that everything run smoothly.

Answer (score 1):

Your DPKG seems to suffer from a package database issue, you can check the /var/log/dpkg.log to see if there is something useful. APT is for managing the sources that contain DPKG packages. normally APT is all you need, but here you may need to force a reinstall of the packages with dpkg -i --force-all one at a time beginning with the dependancies that you first download as deb file

the "apt update" fetches the latest package information, an "apt upgrade" would have downloaded and upgraded the packages, but since you do an "apt install --only-upgrade certbot" it will try to only upgrade certbot, which needs it's python packages as well, but you asked only to upgrade certbot.

APT is downloading all the packages to /var/cache/apt/ and you can remove those packages with "apt clean", but you seem to have issues with apt, it it's really diskspace related, you can check the disk space usage and availability on /boot and /var/cache/apt/ with df

```
df -h /boot/
df -h /var/cache/apt/
```

if apt hangs because of this diskspace in /boot/, you can remove it directly from the harddisk, but be super careful not to remove the latest kernel! you are still using it, it's loaded in memory so a next boot will fail!

```
cd /boot/
ls -la
```

So if you have two kernels
vmlinuz-4.4.0-71-generic
vmlinuz-4.4.0-178-generic

You can remove everything related to the oldest version e.g.

```
sudo rm /boot/*-4.4.0-71-generic
```

Comment: I had 95% space occupied, after removing most of the old kernels i have 89%. But all the commands give the same output.